# Shell script to setup Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, terminal-emulator, xfce

I wanted to create a file I could run every time I installed Xubuntu so I could have my setup ready easier. So I created a python file with the following text to install software, I then set up permissions and ran the file.
It didn't ask for my password and didn't do anything. I made sure I don't already have google chrome installed.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('cd /tmp')
os.system('wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb')
os.system('sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb')
os.system('sudo apt-get -f install')
```

Update:
I have rewritten it as a shell script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt purge gnome-software gnome-sudoku gnome-mines thunderbird pidgin firefox libreoffice
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:richardgv/compton
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pycharm-community gnome-boxes compton synaptic abiword gnumeric ubuntu-restricted-extras
compton -CG
```

I would like to know if there is a line I can add to have the compositor compton and the terminal for XFCE to start upon startup.

Comment: Can you check the return value of each system() call to see where it is failing?

Comment: Probably be better off creating a shell script instead of python for this, which will allow you to interact with the processes to provide passwords if necessary.  To do it in python, you'd have to wrap stdin and stdout and pass the input/output back and forth to the subprocesses.

Comment: You should probably be using `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_output` here instead of `os.system` as well